# Excel / VBA / Bloomberg adjusted prices

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I'm using Excel and VBA to Analyse some data for a assignment in University. At my University I can download the from Bloomberg, I'm doing this via a VBA code. I don't have any formulas in Excel.

My question is how can I get Price and Return Data which are adjusted for dividends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn’t matter if you download the data via VBA, Excel directly, or with any another program like R for example: Bloomberg will always give you the data based your terminal/account settings. If you like to have prices and returns that are adjusted for dividends do the following:

1. Log in to your Bloomberg Terminal/Account
2. `DPDF <go>`
3. Change the Settings for Abnormal/Normal/Cash Dividends and Historical Pricing (if all boxes are checked you will have the desired functionality)

Comment: You don't have to change the terminal settings: you can override them in Excel or VBA.